# Using jQuery to access a SF Controller variable

Tags: controller, jquery

'lo everyone.  I have been trying to use jQuery to access a variable in my controller and I have just not been able to put it together.  So, I created a simple example to eliminate anything extra, but still no success.  Here is what I have; first, my controller ::

```
public with sharing class controllerJQuery {
    public String  strTest { get; set; } { strTest = 'Example'; }
}
```

and my VF page is ::

```
<apex:page controller="controllerJQuery" >

<head>
    <!-- jQuery files -->
    <apex:includeScript value="{!(URLFOR($Resource.jQuery_1_11_0))}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!(URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI_1_10_4))}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!(URLFOR($Resource.jQueryCookie_1_4_0))}" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function queryMyVar() {
//  jQuery('[id$=jQueryID]').val(node.data.key);
//  jQuery('[id$=dsAggregateID]').val(node.data.dsKey);
//  jQuery('[id$=dsAggregateLabel]').val(node.data.title);

    var  strMyTest = $j('[id$=strTestId]').val();
    var  strMyTest2 = $j('[id$=strTestId]').text();

    var  vTest = $j('#strTestId');
    var  strJunk = vTest.val();
    var  strJunk2 = vTest.text();
}

//  **********

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j( document ).ready( queryMyVar() );

</script>
</head>

<apex:form id="formJQuery" >
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!strTest}" id="strTestId" />

<!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
<h1>Congratulations</h1>
This is your new Page
<!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My thoughts/needs are to take the selection of an item in a dropdown list, issue a request for a list of items it describes and then load that into a tree control.

Help?  Advice??

Thank You! in advance for your time & help !

-Scott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is this line:

```
$j( document ).ready( queryMyVar() );
```

that should instead be this:

```
$j( document ).ready( queryMyVar );
```

In your version you are invoking the function immediately it is encountered (as the head element is parsed and before the input field is in the DOM) whereas in the corrected version a reference to the function is being passed and jQuery will invoke that function when the page is "ready" (all elements parsed and in the DOM including the input field).

(And as @BritishBoyinDC shows using `alert` - or `console.log` with your browser's JavaScript console displayed - is a good way to see what is going on.)

Comment: Okay.  I removed the parens and it worked for the strMyTest variable.  Thank You very much for that bit of advice because I do not understand the finer points of how jQuery gets itself up and running within a page loading.  I am learning of course, but still, lots to learn and you have helped.

Comment: Also, yes, I have been using the console in Chrome, learning how to use it, watching variables and the like.  Still have much to learn with it, but each day gets a little further along !!

Comment: @ScottGuillot Great that you are learning about your browser's developer tools - they are very powerful these days (and need to be given the big client-side frameworks we are moving towards).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - I am using CDN for jQuery, but you can replace that part.

I changed the jquery Id wildcard to be a * because VF builds a special unique Id, so you need to search for ends with Id in jQuery to make that work.

I also changed the document ready to be a function...

```
<apex:page controller="controllerJQuery">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var  strMyTest;

function queryMyVar() {
    strMyTest =  $j('[id*=strTestId]').val();
  }

$j(document).ready( function() {
queryMyVar(); 
alert(strMyTest);
});

</script>

<apex:form id="formJQuery" >
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!strTest}" id="strTestId" />

<!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
<h1>Congratulations</h1>
This is your new Page
<!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```