# Does any one know how to pass a salesforce controller variable to a jquery method?

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

I need to pass a string variable that is in the controller  to a jquery method that is on the visualforce page. Here is a dummy code of what i would like to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       if focusedProject.innCode == ProjectTab.innCode {
          ProjectTab.cssClass('.activeState')
       }
 });
```

FocusedProject is the variable in the controller projectTab is a class of the jquery ui tab which holds a projects name and code in it, if the focused project matches the name of the tab's project that tab must become the active tab. 
My current code displays the proper data for that project, however the wrong project tab is active.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Have a look on this !!                                                                                     http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/35031/using-jquery-to-access-a-sf-controller-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       if ('{!JSENCODE(focusedProject.innCode)}' == ProjectTab.innCode {
          ProjectTab.cssClass('.activeState')
       }
 });
```

The basic idea is, we use Apex variables in Visualforce using `{!<apex variable>}` syntax.

Comment: Don't forget to JSENCODE.

Comment: thnx @sfdcfox, just edited my answer to include that.